# Issue while Fetching tweets using Flume

Tags: hadoop, flume

I'm able to fetch tweets using flume, however, the language in which it is streamed is not what I want. Below is the flume.conf file

[image: flume.conf]

And the tweets that I'm getting is shown below:

[image: tweets]

Can anyone suggest changes that I need to make.?

Answer (score 0):

The `TwitterSource` in Apache Flume currently does not implement support for language filtering.  This prior question describes a procedure (admittedly complex) by which you could deploy your own patched version of the code with language support:

[Flume - TwitterSource language filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901714/flume-twittersource-language-filter)

I think it would be a valuable enhancement for Apache Flume to support language filtering.  I encourage you to file a request in Apache JIRA in the [FLUME](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/FLUME) project.

If you're interested, please also consider contributing a patch.  I think it would just be a matter of pulling the "language" setting out of configuration in the `configure` method, saving it in a member variable, and then passing it along in the Twitter4J APIs.